# JSPX leads to copy-paste code?

Tags: jspx

As soon as JSPX must be a well-formed XML, there is no way of having header part including beginig of  tag in separate included file, since  must be closed.

Looks like you must always include  into all of your main pages?
Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Tiles supposedly solves this problem, it allows you to template and re-use JSPX components.

Updated answer:

In your views.xml, you would have something like the following:

```
<definition extends="error" name="dataAccessFailure">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/dataAccessFailure.jspx"/>
</definition>

<definition extends="default" name="index">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/body/index.jspx"/>
    <put-attribute name="side" value="/WEB-INF/views/side/index.jspx"/>
</definition>
```

Both error and default are layouts I've defined in the layouts directory, error is a single column layout and default is a two column layout.

Also in the layouts directory is the layouts.xml:

```
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="default" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/header.jspx" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/views/navigation.jspx" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/footer.jspx" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="error" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/error.jspx">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/header.jspx" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/views/navigation.jspx" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/footer.jspx" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

I haven't personally done apache tiles integration by hand, I just use Spring ROO to generate a complete stack for me and then add / remove stuff as I need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, appreciate that, could you please give me an example how I can do it, having just opening tags in a separate file?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some basic tiles code.
Each file will need valid XML, unlike PHP where you can leave html tags open in separate files.

Comment: So, basically, you are confirming my worst expectations: if I want to have open tag in one file and close in another (like for html tag) I will have to opt-out for JSPs instead of JSPX? Did I get you right?

Comment: Both JSP and JSPX requires valid xml, in other words closed tags.
Apache Tiles templating is the way to go.